# Why is std::wcout not working after using FillConsoleOutputCharacter()?

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I am currently working on a simple console application that is to become a text-based RPG game based on economy. I have an 80x20 (character cells) window that will work as my display.

I have been experimenting with the `FillConsoleOutputCharacter()` API function, which seems to work as desired for clearing the console.

Before I use the function, I have simple output using `wcout` to display certain characteristics, such as the screen buffer size and the window size; but after outputting with `FillConsoleOutputCharacter()`, I notice that `wcout` does not output as it should.

I have the API function nested in another function named `clearConsole()`, and have noticed that output using `wcout` works as it should after leaving the function, but not after the call to `FillConsoleOutputCharacter()` (within the function).

Here is the function:

```
void clearConsole(HANDLE screen)
{
    DWORD cCharsWritten;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO bufferInfo;
    DWORD dwConsoleSz;
    
    if(!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(screen, &bufferInfo))
    {
        return;
    }

    dwConsoleSz = bufferInfo.dwSize.X * bufferInfo.dwSize.Y; /* This should be equivalent to the number of character cells in the buffer. */

    /* Now we fill the entire screen with blanks. */
    if(!FillConsoleOutputCharacter(
            screen,
            L' ',
            dwConsoleSz,
            cursorHome,
            &cCharsWritten
        ));
    {
        return;
    }

    /* Then we get the current text attribute (maybe unnecessary?) */
    if(!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(screen, &bufferInfo)) /* Perhaps the ScreenBuffer needs to be set again, see SetConsoleCursorPosition. */
    {
        return;
    }

    /* And set the buffer's attributes accordingly. */
    if(!FillConsoleOutputAttribute(
            screen,
            bufferInfo.wAttributes,
            dwConsoleSz,
            cursorHome,
            &cCharsWritten
        ))
    {
        return;
    }

    if(!SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, bufferInfo.dwCursorPosition))
        /*Research is needed regarding this function as it does not seem to move the cursor. */
    {
        wcout << L"SetConsoleCursorPosition failed. Error Code: " << GetLastError();
        system("pause");
    }

    wcout << L"Screen Buffer Size: " << bufferInfo.dwSize.X << L',' << bufferInfo.dwSize.Y << L'\n' << L"Cursor Position: " <<
            bufferInfo.dwCursorPosition.X << L',' << bufferInfo.dwCursorPosition.Y << L'\n' <<
            L"Buffer Top X: " << bufferInfo.srWindow.Left << L' ' <<  L"Buffer Top Y: " << bufferInfo.srWindow.Top << L'\n' << L"Buffer Bottom X : " << bufferInfo.srWindow.Right << L' ' << L"Buffer Bottom Y: " << bufferInfo.srWindow.Bottom << L'\n';
            
    wcout << L"hello from clearConsole" << L'\n'; 
    /* wcout stops working from within this function after FillConsoleOutputCharacter is
        called. But for some odd reason it begins working again after the function ends.
    */
    Sleep(1000);
    return;
}
```

What could be the cause for this?

I have experimented with moving the `wcout` lines around within the nesting function, and have seen that it works before the call to the API function, but not after. A strange malfunction. Flushing `wcout` (or the output stream) does not solve the issue, either.

Setting the cursor back to `(0,0)` does not seem to place the cursor back at the top left corner of the console, either. `screen` is a global variable set to `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE`.

**EDIT:** Also, trying to set the cursor back to `(0,0)` using a global `COORD` object `cursorHome` in the call to `SetConsoleCursorPosition()` before writing to output does not seem to work, either.

**EDIT:** Setting the cursor's position after the call to `clearConsole()` works as well. What could be the cause of this strange behavior?

Comment: "screen" is a global variable set to STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE. This is probably wrong. It should be set to GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ).

Comment: BTW: Did you step through your code with the debugger ? If not ,you should. I suspect you return from the function because of a failed API call.

Comment: You know, I am interested in this. How can I do so from the VS Developer Command Prompt (i.e. "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt)?

Comment: I never work with the command prompt ,so I don't know. From inside Visual studio : press F5 for debugging (and ctrl-F5 for run without debugging). you can place break-points in your code by pressing F9 on the lines where you want to pause the execution of your code. When debugging in VS you'll have a 'debug toolbar' with some options ,a.o. for stepping line by line. Just experiment with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After multiple tests. It is caused by a very minor error - the `;` after `FillConsoleOutputCharacter()`.

```
/* Now we fill the entire screen with blanks. */
if(!FillConsoleOutputCharacter(
        screen,
        L' ',
        dwConsoleSz,
        cursorHome,
        &cCharsWritten
    )); // <-- HERE
{
    return;
}
```

It cuts off the front and back connection and destroys the logic. It means that whatever value is returned by `FillConsoleOutputCharacter()` has nothing to do with the content in `{ }`.

Just delete it.

Comment: This solved it. Good catch, I'm not sure how a simple error was missed by the compiler. I'll have to pay better attention. Thank you, good sir.

Comment: @nore "*I'm not sure how a simple error was missed by the compiler*" - you probably don't have its warning level turned up high enough. Most compilers *do* warn about mistakes like this.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see: I knew there was a benefit of moving from VS to the Native Tools Command Prompt.